# Where is vuex physically stored?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuex, store

How can i access vuex data using the console or any other method when my vue app is on production?

Can't use Vue Devtools because i am on production

Comment: From where do you want to access it?

Comment: You would probably have to attach the store or vue instance with store access, to the window object and access it from there

Comment: @Justice I'm talking about the persistance. I guessed that's what OP was asking since the question is not very clear (I extrapolated from the "physically" word in the title).

Comment: @BillalBegueradj Console or window object

Comment: @Seblor, I am not talking about persistance, just any way to access it

Comment: @Justice, I did that, but i was searching if there is a native solution

Comment: @Justice, if not localStorage, where? What other storage component, aside from the DB itself, could hold state between refresh?

Comment: @Li357 Why would it be a security risk? It's client-side. Client-side stuff should always assumed to be available to an attacker.

Comment: @I'mOnlyVueman Vuex by itself doesn't maintain state between refresh. You'd need to add the state to localStorage manually or use a plugin to do that

Comment: @I'mOnlyVueman - where in the question do you see anything about holding state between a refresh?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access the Vuex store from the dev console by querying any element that has Vue properties. For example:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].__vue__.$store
```

If you are using nuxt, you can also access it from

```
window.$nuxt.$store
```

Comment: Very cool. Using the `id` of the root Vue element would be a more general solution: `document.getElementById('app').__vue__.$store`

Comment: Yes, if your app binds to the default #app